# Pushing a subdirectory and its contents to an established remote repo

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble understanding how to `git push` a sub-directory of a local repo directory to Github. For example, I have an established git connection with Gibhub that contains only the main directory and the .py script inside (project/script.py). I added a 'db' sub-directory with a single .json file inside (project/db/list.json). I want to push project/db/list.json to my Github to the already established directory (project) on the same branch.

Do you I need to `git init` in the sub-directory or is it possible to simply push the actual sub-directory?

Comment: You can *add* a file to your repository by running `git add db/list.json` from the top level of your repository, then commititng that change with `git commit`. At this point you have updated your local repository and you can push the changes by running `git push` (possibly with additional options depending on how things are configured). You may want to spend some time reading through [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: Now if I `git add` a file in a sub-directory will that sub-directory also push to my remote repo because the remote ONLY has the main directory /project/, not /project/db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always push the all repository, meaning all the commits you have done since your last push.

One of those commits might involve files from one folder, but that is not mandatory: you cam make a commit with changes from multiple folders.

In your case, as commented, add and commit your subfolder content. You can then push it.

Comment: Will the actual sub-directory folder also be pushed and thus be created in the remote repo?

Comment: @bighelpdiscord Yes, the remote repository will be the mirror image of the all local repository you just committed then pushed. If the local repository has a non-empty folder (whose content was added/committed), the remote repository will have the same non-empty folder after a push.

Comment: OK - I was reading the docs and I was interpreting as I would have had to create the sub-directory and then `git init` . It didn't seem like the correct way to do it. So to summarize I would do `git add /project/db/list.json` - `git commit -m "new sub"` - `git push` and my remote repo (github) will automatically create the db folder for me and populate the folder with list.json. Is this correct?

Comment: @bighelpdiscord That would create a nested Git repository, which is bad. So add/commit push is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

In git you have a specific workflow to follow.

1. Do work in your git-project
2. **Add files** to the staging area

   - git add
3. **Commit the staged files** to the local repository

   - git commit
4. **Pulling** the remote repository

   - git pull
5. **Pushing** your local repository to remote

   - git push

To answer your question: After changing files in your project, you can add specific files to the staging area. Only these staged changes get commited and pushed in the following steps.

Like larsk pointed out, [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) contains very helpful and further information about git.

Comment: I understand the basics so far, but I can't find in the docs if the actual sub-directory folder also pushes. For example, if I `git add /project/db/.json` , commit, then push, will the actual sub-directory 'db' file also be created at the remote repo?

Comment: @bighelpdiscord Yes it will. See my comment below.